# How to remotely update android app information?

Tags: android, networking

I am working on an app that would have a couple of text views that change based on menu items. I currently have a method for doing this involving socket communication between a constantly running server and the app, but I don't want to have a constantly running server and computer. Is there some way to send an update (without updating the entire app) to send menu changes from a computer to the app? Thanks for any and all help, I will clarify if needed.

Comment: What kind of way are you looking for? Anyway, there should be a server which will send data to your device, so I don't really understand what you're searching for.

Comment: I want a way to change the text in the app if a menu item changes, but I don't want to have a constantly running server. Maybe the server could send data to all devices at once?